# Finding multiple Values in NSMutable Array

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I want to find multiple values in one NSMutableArray. Like if this two values found then in this array then i want to execute my condition.For Example
this is my array

NSMutableArray findValues have 1,2,3,4,5.Now i want to put condition like this

```
if([findvalues have string @"1"] && [findValues have string @"4"]){

    //execute code

}
```

can anyone suggest how to do this?

Comment: use if (yourArray.containsobject(yourObject)) {//Object find};

Comment: Why are those numbers in strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use following code to find object in Array,

```
if ([array containsObject:@"1"] && [array containsObject:@"4"]) {
        //execute code
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

use [containsObject:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/containsObject:)

```
if([findvalues containsObject:@"1"] && [findValues containsObject:@"4"]){

    //execute code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use below code:

```
  if ([findvalues containsObject:@"1"] && [findvalues containsObject:@"4"]) {

    // Do something here...
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

To filter array by multiple values, use NSPredicate

Create an object class, which contains an object value and compare the text by using given format

```
NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(value   contains[c] %@) || (value contains[c] %@)", @"f", @"x"];

NSMutableArray* list = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[findValues filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]];
```

Hope this solution helps you.. Thanks